# Increase width of content area on Woocommerce shop page, keep sidebar

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, width, wrapper, product

I have been trying to figure out how to increase the width of the wrapper that encloses the content area and the sidebar as a whole so it takes up more of the sides. I want to display large images with at least 4 products per row.

I tried changing the wrapper width in the stylesheet as well as the grid class size but either the sidebar drops to the bottom or the products won't stay on the same row even though I have it set to 4 products per row.

I've tried messing with every CSS width I could find and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this. Every solution I've found doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks.

My site is www.Lucidwerx.com

```
.wrapper,
.layout-boxed {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}

.grids{margin-left:-30px}
.grid-1,.grid-2,.grid-3,.grid-4,.grid-5,.grid-6,.grid-7,.grid-8,.grid-9,.grid-10,.grid-11,.grid-12{display:inline;float:left;margin-left:30px}
.grid-12{margin-right:0}

.grid-4:nth-child(3n+1) {clear:left;}
.grid-8 .grid-4:nth-child(3n+1),
.grid-8 .grid-2:nth-child(3n+1) {clear:none;}
.grid-8 .grid-4:nth-child(odd),
.grid-8 .grid-2:nth-child(4n+1) {clear:left;}

/* Grid 1080px */
.wrapper{width:1050px}
.grid-1{width:60px}.grid-2{width:150px}.grid-3{width:240px}.grid-4{width:330px}.grid-5{width:420px}.grid-6{width:510px}.grid-7{width:600px}.grid-8{width:690px}.grid-9{width:780px}.grid-10{width:870px}.grid-11{width:960px}.grid-12{width:1500px}
.layout-boxed {max-width:1500px;}

/* Grid 960px (mediaqueries) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.wrapper{width:930px}
.grid-1{width:50px}.grid-2{width:130px}.grid-3{width:210px}.grid-4{width:290px}.grid-5{width:370px}.grid-6{width:450px}.grid-7{width:530px}.grid-8{width:610px}.grid-9{width:690px}.grid-10{width:770px}.grid-11{width:850px}.grid-12{width:910px}
.layout-boxed {max-width:990px;}
}

/*Grid 750px (mediaqueries)*/ 
@media only screen and (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 959px) {
.wrapper{width:700px}
.grids{margin-left:-20px}
.grid-1,.grid-2,.grid-3,.grid-4,.grid-5,.grid-6,.grid-7,.grid-8,.grid-9,.grid-10,.grid-11,.grid-12{margin-left:20px}
.grid-1{width:40px}.grid-2{width:100px}.grid-3{width:160px}.grid-4{width:220px}.grid-5{width:280px}.grid-6{width:340px}.grid-7{width:400px}.grid-8{width:460px}.grid-9{width:520px}.grid-10{width:580px}.grid-11{width:640px}.grid-12{width:680px}
.layout-boxed {max-width:730px;}
}

/* Mobile (mediaqueries) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px){
.grids,
.grid-1,.grid-2,.grid-3,.grid-4,.grid-5,.grid-6,.grid-7,.grid-8,.grid-9,.grid-10,.grid-11,.grid-12{width:100%;margin-left:0;margin-right:0}
html{font-size:1.125em}
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 750px) {
.wrapper{width:417px}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.wrapper{width:273px}   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 240px) {
.wrapper{width:200px}   
}

[class*="grid-"] .wrapper{width:100%}
```

I think I finally got it to how I want it to look. I used this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
 width: 29%;
 }

.sidebar {
    width: 60%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) 
{
       .woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
        {
                width: 98% !important;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't properly test this code because you only have 3 products added but here is some CSS that will improve the layout of your page.  Ideally you would probably need to modify the page template and change the classes being used for the product and widget columns to give the products more room and make the filter smaller.  At the moment the products are wrapped in a 'grid-8' class.  The code below will give you some improvement you can play around with the values. I also add a media query so that on smaller screen devices the products are displayed full screen width.  Insert it into your style.css or through the console of whatever theme you are using.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 95% !important;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 22% !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I added an additional product and posted the css that seems to be controlling it. I looked at the grid-8 class info and it does show a fixed pixel which I tried increasing the width size and it still doesn't seem to look right. Also, the media query sizes seem to already be there.

Comment: Yea just depends how many products you want it to show per row on mobile devices, looks like it is showing 2 per row at the moment.  I changed the width to 22% for the product list and it displays 4 columns of products but it will be dependent on your desktop resolution.  http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7395/fNVXGV.png

Comment: I plugged your code in and this is how it looks on my screen: [https://i.imgur.com/F3cGHmy.png](https://i.imgur.com/F3cGHmy.png) - the images look smaller and it shifts all the way to the left.

Comment: Yes like I stated you need to modify the template and change the grid classes so that they take up a majority of the space for the products.  Currently it's using grid-8 class for the products but if you use grid-10 it looks much better.  The only problem is that your screen resolution looks super high and the theme uses static pixel width instead of percentages so you'll see a lot of white space on large resolutions. Attached is what it looks like on my 13" laptop http://imageshack.com/a/img922/8052/mDpx83.png